# Call function inside a javascript file on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a javascript file and inside it there are some functions. I can call them on my rails app view through onclick events like: ...onclick="myFunnyFunction();"... and it works. But now I want to call this myFunnyFunction(); using the onload event like: onload="myFunnyFunction();". Both calls are in the same view file (one in a button and one in a div) and the onclick event work but the onload event don't. The div is showing the html properly so it is loaded.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If body onload not works mean try this , operations are same

```
window.onLoad = doStuff()

function doStuff() {
   alert("test")
}
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3SeM2/)

you cant do it div onload method but its posible you put script after div it will work

```
<div id="somid">Some content</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   yourfunction()
</script>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. In your case you launch the function when the body is loaded, but I want to launch the function when a particular div is loaded. Is that possible?

Comment: Great! it was simple but I couldn't figure it out. Thanks!